# Not able to set constraints in XIB - Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib, xcode11.3

I created a project in Swift. I added view controller file and one XIB using right click on the project - > Add Files to projectname -> Empty (xib) file.

After adding the xib file, i removed the view and added View Controller. Under the View controller , i have added few button. But i am not able set the constraints.But if i add the View object instead of View Controller, i am able to set the constraints. I don't understand why the xib constraints are disabled for View controller. Attached the screen shot

[image]

Comment: Why would you put a view controller in a xib? If you want to design a view controller, use a storyboard. Your Layout pop up menu in the screen shot means “no constraints” by the way.

Comment: you mean to say we should not use xib to create UIViewController. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

Layout is set to `Translates Mask Into Constraints`, meaning that IB is gonna generate the constraints for you automatically.
Set it to `Automatic` and it'll work.

[image]